# R data.table compiled installation failing: Error: shared object ‘datatable.so’ not found

Tags: r, data.table

I'm installing R on a new laptop (no migration from a previous laptop or OS version).
R 4.0.1 installed fine.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.1 tools_4.0.1
```

Then I move on to install data.table:

```
> install.packages("data.table")
trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/data.table_1.12.8.tgz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 2070859 bytes (2.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.0 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/tg/5sw17w2n28g_2n1c_cs0ydlw0000gn/T//RtmpU0QnBY/downloaded_packages
```

Seems fine. But when I load it:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 1 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
**********
This installation of data.table has not detected OpenMP support. It should still work but in single-threaded mode. If this is a Mac, please ensure you are using R>=3.4.0 and have followed our Mac instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation. This warning message should not occur on Windows or Linux. If it does, please file a GitHub issue.
**********
```

I want to use multiple cores so I go to the suggested web page above and follow instructions there. I do all three steps and they all seem to work (no error messages).

1. install command line tools with "xcode-select --install"
2. install Brew and then "brew update && brew install llvm"
3. finally create and edit "~/.R/Makevars" as suggested.

At this point I go back and try installing data.table and compiling it with:

```
> install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
+     repos = "https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table")
trying URL 'https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/src/contrib/data.table_1.12.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/gzip' length 5207555 bytes (5.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** using staged installation
*** pkg-config is not installed.
*** Compilation will now be attempted and if it works you can ignore this message. However,
*** if compilation fails, try 'locate zlib.h zconf.h' and ensure the zlib development library
*** is installed :
***   deb: zlib1g-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
***   rpm: zlib-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
***   brew: zlib (OSX)
*** Note that zlib is required to compile R itself so you may find the advice in the R-admin
*** guide helpful regarding zlib. On Debian/Ubuntu, zlib1g-dev is a dependency of r-base as
*** shown by 'apt-cache showsrc r-base | grep ^Build-Depends | grep zlib', and therefore
*** 'sudo apt-get build-dep r-base' should be sufficient too.
*** To silence this message, please ensure that :
***   1) 'pkg-config --exists zlib' succeeds (i.e. $? -eq 0)
***   2) 'pkg-config --libs zlib' contains -lz
*** Compilation will now be attempted ...
** libs
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c assign.c -o assign.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c between.c -o between.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c bmerge.c -o bmerge.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c chmatch.c -o chmatch.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c cj.c -o cj.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c coalesce.c -o coalesce.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c dogroups.c -o dogroups.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fastmean.c -o fastmean.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fcast.c -o fcast.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fifelse.c -o fifelse.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fmelt.c -o fmelt.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c forder.c -o forder.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c frank.c -o frank.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fread.c -o fread.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c freadR.c -o freadR.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c froll.c -o froll.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c frollR.c -o frollR.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c frolladaptive.c -o frolladaptive.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fsort.c -o fsort.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fwrite.c -o fwrite.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c fwriteR.c -o fwriteR.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c gsumm.c -o gsumm.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c ijoin.c -o ijoin.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c init.c -o init.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c inrange.c -o inrange.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c nafill.c -o nafill.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c nqrecreateindices.c -o nqrecreateindices.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c openmp-utils.c -o openmp-utils.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c quickselect.c -o quickselect.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c rbindlist.c -o rbindlist.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c reorder.c -o reorder.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c shift.c -o shift.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c snprintf.c -o snprintf.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c subset.c -o subset.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c transpose.c -o transpose.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c types.c -o types.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c uniqlist.c -o uniqlist.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c utils.c -o utils.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c vecseq.c -o vecseq.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c wrappers.c -o wrappers.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -o data.table.so assign.o between.o bmerge.o chmatch.o cj.o coalesce.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fcast.o fifelse.o fmelt.o forder.o frank.o fread.o freadR.o froll.o frollR.o frolladaptive.o fsort.o fwrite.o fwriteR.o gsumm.o ijoin.o init.o inrange.o nafill.o nqrecreateindices.o openmp-utils.o quickselect.o rbindlist.o reorder.o shift.o snprintf.o subset.o transpose.o types.o uniqlist.o utils.o vecseq.o wrappers.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-data.table/00new/data.table/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘datatable.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/data.table’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/tg/5sw17w2n28g_2n1c_cs0ydlw0000gn/T/RtmpU0QnBY/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("data.table", type = "source", repos = "https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table") :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
```

Didn't work.

What does the error message mean "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
shared object ‘datatable.so’ not found" ???

Comment: I don't remember seeing these messages about zlib when doing this on my mac (but I might have overlooked them since my install was successful). Have you followed the advice from these messages?

Comment: I think you're suggesting I try `locate zlib.h zconf.h`. This results in a list of about 10 directories mostly like `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/...`

Comment: could you please file an issue in data.table issue tracker?

Comment: I added this issue to GitHub data.table #4574.